# How do you move one row to the next empty row if a cell has data?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a function or VBA code in Excel that checks; if a cell has text data > move that row to another row on the same sheet.

Ie. In Table 2 the middle column **has data** > move that row from Table 2 to the next empty row in Table 1.

Table 1

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |
| left | center | right |
|  |  |  |

Table 2

| left | **has data** | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One |  | Three |

Comment: Yes you can do that with VBA - did you already try anything?

Comment: I've watch a video regarding this and tried playing around with it but to no avail. And the methods weren't completed automated and still used Macros.